# How translate humanize django

Tags: django, translate, humanize

I need translate humanize to portuguese (pt-BR). How?

Import:

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime
```

Using:

```
_question['pub_date'] = naturaltime(question.pub_date)
```

Settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

And in my template show this:

```
2 hours ago
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in the template?

Comment: Yes, I doing this inside django (in amazon server) so maybe he get english like default language. I set inside template and works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just need set humanize inside template and works.

```
<span>{{question.pub_date|naturaltime}}</span>
```

You need add in installed apps too

```
'django.contrib.humanize',
```